# Generate Missing date and add zero value and add one to existing date in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am new to sql and I need to generate missing date and add value 0 and for existing date value as 1.

refereed many example on generating missing date in sql all show, adding 0 to missing date but no solution to add 1 to existing date

i have a table called Alarm and column Alarm_start, Alarm_Start has below data.

```
2019-03-24 11:36:24.000
2019-03-25 07:47:49.000
2019-03-27 09:40:39.000
2019-03-29 10:04:43.000
```

result needed is only with date and 0 and 1

```
2019-03-24     1
2019-03-25     1
2019-03-26     0
2019-03-27     1
2019-03-28     0
2019-03-29     1
```

Comment: Create a `Date Table` in your database and drive off that table and `LEFT JOIN` to your `Alarm` table. That will give you your missing dates within your date range that you specify.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, we data with date ranges varying to years like from previous years too, adding all those dates inside Date table will become maintenance issue. i am very new to sql can you please share some sample

Comment: Just create whatever range you need for the dates. A decade is 3650 rows, 100 years is still a tiny table.

Comment: thanks can you pls share some sample on how to store dates from 2018 to 2028 and store in a table permanently and then left join with Alarm table data of mine

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Please try following

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME

SET @StartDateTime = '1/1/2019'
SET @EndDateTime = '12/31/2019';

--delete from #tmp

;WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT DateRange.DateData, CASE WHEN Your_table.DateCol IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS NUM
FROM DateRange LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(VALUES ('1/1/2019'),('1/3/2019')) AS Your_table(DateCol)
ON DateRange.DateData  = CAST(Your_table.DateCol AS date)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm, exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your question, you are looking for output that shows whether or not a date within a range has a record in your table (output = 1), or does not have a record (output = 0).

**Assumption**: You will have a start and end date for your query, e.g. `... BETWEEN '2019-03-24' AND '2019-03-29'`

The easiest way to do this is with a "Tally Table", also called a "Numbers Table". This is a table object containing a sequence of numbers, starting with 0 or 1, and ending at whatever number you need. For this example, I will create a dynamic tally table, but you may find that you want to keep a permanent tally table somewhere in your database so you don't have to create it on the fly each time.

```
DECLARE @startDate date = '2019-03-24'
DECLARE @endDate date = 2019-03-29

-- Get the number of days between start and end date
DECLARE @days int
SET @days = datediff (day, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1  -- Add 1 so you have six days total

-- Build the tally table
-- NOTE: Must use SELECT...INTO to user the IDENTITY function.
-- DECLARE @Tally TABLE (N int not null primary key)
```

--    INSERT INTO @Tally (N)
    SELECT TOP (@days)
        IDENTITY(INT,0,1) AS N
    INTO #Tally
    FROM master.sys.syscolumns sc1
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.syscolumns sc2
    -- NOTE: there are other ways to create a tally table. This is just one example
    -- NOTE: In SQL 2016, there are more than 15,000 rows in the master.dbo.syscolumns table.
    --       The cross join may be unnecessary for your needs. If so, you can rewrite this as:
    --    INSERT INTO @Tally (N)
    --    SELECT TOP (@days)
    --        IDENTITY(INT,0,1) AS N
    --    FROM master.sys.syscolumns sc

```
-- Since your dynamic tally table has only the number of entries you need, no special
--  filtering on the table is needed. However, if you have too many rows, an index
--  on the N field will help.  Simply use CREATE INDEX Idx1 ON #Tally(N)

;WITH Dates as (
   SELECT Dateadd(day, t.N, @StartDate) As CheckDate
   FROM #Tally
   )
SELECT CheckDate,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Alarm WHERE Convert(date, Alarm_Start) = CheckDate)
            Then 1
        Else 0
    END As Alarm_Exists
FROM Dates
ORDER BY CheckDate
```

Comment: It is showing me The IDENTITY function can only be used when the SELECT statement has an INTO clause. error,pls help

Comment: Code above edited to use a #temp table instead of an @temp table.